# Element not moving to the right location after setting position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-position

I am using this code to move an element around based on `keydown` event:

```js
$("body").on("keydown", function(event) {
    var arrow_position = $(".down-arrow").position();

    if(event.key == 's') {
        $(".down-arrow").css({"top": arrow_position.top - 10});
    }
    if(event.key == 'w') {
        $(".down-arrow").css({"top": arrow_position.top + 10});
    }
    if(event.key == 'a') {
        $(".down-arrow").css({"left": arrow_position.left - 10});
    }
    if(event.key == 'd') {
        $(".down-arrow").css({"left": arrow_position.left + 10});
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: var(--font-family);
  font-size: 4rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  /* width: 1920px; */
  /* height: 1080px; */
}

.down-arrow {
  left: 58%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  transform: rotate(170deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="down-arrow">

</div>
```

The element is directly inside the body.

However, the element only moves left when I press either `a` or `d`. Similarly, it only moves up when I press `s` or `w`. It also moves in increments of 20 instead of 10. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add a complete snippet?  Ideally with the relevant css

Comment: @freedomn-m Thiis is the entire JavaScript code. I will add the CSS now. :)

Comment: Your code works fine(\*) as provided: https://jsfiddle.net/bdtpxLrk/  (\* coordinates 0,0 are top-left so your w/d go the wrong way).  Made some assumptions on css, so will review after you add css.

Comment: Converted to a snippet, and it works fine (added border and fixed size to the div so you can see it).  So what's different between what you've provided here and your code?  Maybe try to recreate the issue somewhere else, such as jsfiddle?

Comment: @freedomn-m I did some checks and there is rotation of 170 degree also applied on the object. How would that affect the movement though?

Comment: I added the question embedded code snippet and this reproduces the issue. Sorry, it took a while to reply, I had to baby sit a kid. :)

Comment: The rotation certainly is the cause of the problem, [without it](https://jsfiddle.net/bdtpxLrk/1/) everything is +/- 10, but [with it](https://jsfiddle.net/bdtpxLrk/2/) it's +5/-15

Comment: No idea why, but if you add `transform-origin:top left` and `translateY(99%) translateX(110%)` (trial and error values) to your transform, it's a *bit* closer:  https://jsfiddle.net/bdtpxLrk/3/  without the transform-origin, add `transform: translateY(8%) translateX(8%) rotate(170deg);`  https://jsfiddle.net/bdtpxLrk/4/

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m It works as expected after the transforms. :)

Comment: Is there any reason why you want ahead with the application of `transform-origin` and `translate` properties? Was it just gut feeling?

Comment: A search on "transform: rotate and left" gave [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32003106/css-rotate-and-position-to-bottom-left-of-page) (not a duplicate) - so tried it out

Comment: The crux of that answer, and it may apply to your scenario, is to apply the transform to the element *inside* the positioned div.   So your left/right will be an exact +/- 10:  https://jsfiddle.net/bdtpxLrk/5/

Comment: Thank you very much @freedomn-m. You have been really helpful. :)